# How do I record a time in a constructor and how do I subtract the current time from construction in the destructor in a C++ Struct?

Tags: c++, unix

I am currently working on an exercise in C++ where I am to create a struct called TimerClass whose constructor records the current time and and a destructor that records that current time and subtracts it from the time of construction (i.e. the current time in the constructor) and prints it to the console. Here is the code that I have so far:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>

struct TimerClass {
    TimerClass(time_t* timestamp) : timestamp(timestamp) {
        std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        printf("The current time is: %s\n", timestamp);
    }

    ~TimerClass() {
        printf("Time since last construction: %s\n", timestamp);
    }

private:
    time_t* timestamp;
};
```

I have tried looking up some possible solutions online without much luck. I am new to C++ and the book that I am learning from does not say how to record time.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono

Comment: `time_t` is the c time api. `chrono` is the c++ api. Both have similar capabilities, but they are not interchangeable. STick with one otr the other, probably `chrono`

Comment: Passing a `time_t` by pointer is an unusual choice and makes `TimerClass` vulnerable to holding a [dangling pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer) or having another holder of this pointer (or the value pointed-at) change the value and make the output of the constructor questionable. It is already questionable  because it flat-out lies about what it prints. A `time_t` should not be formatted as a string. [The results are unpredictable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Comment: If the constructor should record the current time, throwing it away and storing whatever time the creator happened to pass to it doesn't seem like a good idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[std::chrono](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) library is a decent option for your scenario. `steady_clock` is better for this kind of job because it isn't affected from system time, so it is used in the demonstration.

Another tips, don't use pointer anymore unless you don't have another option.
The header which is prefixed with 'c' means library from C language, so it is better to avoid them.

Here is the demonstration, maybe a starting point for you to understand chrono library.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

struct TimerClass {
    TimerClass() 
        :   m_start { std::chrono::steady_clock::now() }
    {}

    ~TimerClass() {
        using namespace std::chrono;
        auto life = steady_clock::now() - m_start;
        std::cout << "Duration in ms " << duration_cast<milliseconds>( life ).count() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Duration in us " << duration_cast<microseconds>( life ).count() << std::endl;
    }

private:
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point m_start;
};

int main()
{
    TimerClass t;

    {
        TimerClass t_2;

        std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::seconds { 1 } );
    }

    std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::milliseconds { 300 } );
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/VFgWDT